# Gmail API Messages List call returns different amount of messages when using "maxResults" parameter

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, filemaker

I'm using the Gmail API to get email messages with a specific subject line. I'm having trouble getting all the messages through the API. The API is working but it's behaving oddly.

I am using the [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) method

When I use the following call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/edds@servesmarter.net/messages?q=before:2021/3/31 after:2021/3/30 subject:(edds notification)
```

The result is:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": "1788594360874bf1"
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "13478803631938655493",
  "resultSizeEstimate": 206
}
```

When I use the following call:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/edds@servesmarter.net/messages?q=before:2021/3/31 after:2021/3/30 subject:(edds notification)&maxResults=500
```

The result is:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": "178",
      "threadId": "178841450114c5a0"
    }
  ],
  "resultSizeEstimate": 189
}
```

When I log into gmail in a browser and type in "before:2021/3/31 after:2021/3/30 subject:(edds notification)" into the search bar, I see 296 results which is what I expected.

I first had the version without the maxResults parameter set up and I just looped until there wasnt a nextPageToken returned. But this isnt working either as it was ending up with 189 emails which is less than the 296 that should actually return. What could be causing this issue? And why would I get less messageIDs when increasing the maxResults to 500 from the default 100?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I didnt check your results but if your sure. I would bug report it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191602%2B

Comment: I just did, hopefully I can get some support. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't hold your breath, i think i still have an outstanding one from 2012